# Java Templates: array of Template Type in Template

Tags: java, class, templates

I would like to implement a template which contains an array of the template Type. Is there a way to do something similar to what I have outlined in my sample code? The problem is in the line where this.foo is assigned a new array of the template type.

```
class Classname<T>
{
  T[] foo
  Classname()
  {
    this.foo=new T[128];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work, and [here is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025837/initialize-java-generic-array-of-type-generic) that explains why. But, practically spoken, an Arraylist is a good replacement, because it basically wraps an array in a list object.

**Edit**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation) is even closer to your problem

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
class Classname<T> {
  T[] foo;
  public Classname(Class<T> klass, int size) {
    this.foo = (T[]) Array.newInstance(klass, size);
  }
}
```

then you should be able to use it like this:

```
Classname<Double> c = new Classname<>(Double.class, 5);
```