# How can one make an array of type Class<? extends something>?

Tags: java, arrays, class, reflection

I have the following code, but it won't compile:

```
Class<? extends something>[] classes = new Class<? extends something>[5]();
```

Why exactly won't this work? And is there a way around this? I also tried it with `Class<?>` and that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure if those parentheses `()` are intentional, but they do not belong there (syntax error). By the way, if you remove them, then `Class<?>` will work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize Java Generic Array of Type Generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025837/initialize-java-generic-array-of-type-generic)

Comment: I clearly explained **why** the following statement doesn't compile. Many answers on SO doesn't explain why it doesn't compile, except by saying that it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer has to do with [Array Creation Expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#46168).

The rule clearly states:

> The rules above imply that the element type in an array creation
>   expression **cannot be a parameterized type, other than an unbounded
>   wildcard**.

That's why your above code will never compile. In fact, the following compile-time error message shows (example):

```
/**
 * 
 */


/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class<? extends Exception>[] classes = new Class<? extends Exception>[5];
    }

}
```

> Test.java:17: generic array creation

Solution (that works, if you follow the above rule):

```
Class<? >[] classes = new Class<?>[5];
```

The above line compiles.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It can however be declared against `Class<? extends Exception>`.

Comment: It must be totally *unbounded* in order for the array to work.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should try removing `()` from the last

```
Class<? extends something>[] classes = new Class<? extends something>[5];
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? Try for instance `Class<? extends Number>[] classes = new Class<? extends Number>[5];`.

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: D'oh! I knew that. It still gives me the same error though "Cannot create a generic array of Class<? extends something>".