# How to create array of concrete parameterized type without using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, warnings, suppress-warnings

I just start to learn Java and I am getting "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")"

I am sure that one of my static variable is making trouble

```
static ArrayList<Integer>[] docNumber = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[20];
```

eclipse said *"Type safety: Unchecked cast from ArrayList[] to ArrayList[]"*
but i am not really sure how to avoid this problem

can you tell me how to fix this problem?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize Java Generic Array of Type Generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025837/initialize-java-generic-array-of-type-generic)

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an array of `ArrayList`?  Maybe you really just want `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer on the post I linked to points to the wrong explanation. See here instead: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104

Answer (score 2):

Can't be avoided with arrays.

Use a `List<List<Integer>>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the `@SuppressWarnings(“unchecked”)` you should give the compiler the information needed to perform all type checks that would be necessary to ensure type safety, see [unchecked FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ001).

In your case, I assume that you are trying to maintain a list of document integers, for this you will need:

```
List<Integer> docNumber=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you would like to keep a list of lists then you can do:

```
List<List<Integer>> docNumber=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this (`List of Array Of Integer`)?

```
   static ArrayList<Integer[]> docNumber = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```